# How to lock cell in google sheet based on date/time using script

Tags: google-sheets, locking

I want to make some cells can entry until specific date/day and time,
in every new wednseday morning pepole can add things but not be deleted..
this is for yoga class that they can be enter their name but not delete it after 8am

this is example, the blue cells are I want to lock at the date i told you.
but to re-open after wednesday 9PM . please feel free to edit

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UdJN9nec86it2P9W6a2uHeGQm2R2D0XCrSzfZg40Djg/edit?usp=sharing

thanks
juoti.k@gmail.com

dont work for me i try

Comment: Your question should stand on its own. Please don't expect that users should/will open your spreadsheet to better understand you scenario or your question. All this information should be explained _in the body of the question_. Also the tag `google-sheets' clearly states:, `Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead.` Would you please edit your  include some sample data as well as an example of a successful outcome.